# Get value from URL with different types of parameters

Tags: permalinks, urls, home-url

I'm kind of new to wordpress. what I want to do is;
For my home page I want to build URL like, `www.example.com/email/abc@example.com`
and fetch value with `email` like

> $wp_query->query['email']

but for other pages, 
my URL will be like `www.example.com/dashboard` etc.

Can I do it in wordpress? If yes, how can I do it? **I want to do it with pretty permalinks.**

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be sort of:

echo home_url( 'email").'/'.$_GET['email'];

read more from https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

Comment: thanks for replying but it doesn't work. :(